# How to return an array from array of arrays using pop - Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I have an array of arrays in Perl and I need the array at the rear end. I used pop() and as per its description it should return the last element in the array(which itself is an array in my case). But I notice that pop() returns a 2-D array(with 1 row and no. of columns equal to the no. of columns in the last array which had to be popped out). Can I somehow make pop() return only an array instead of an array of arrays?

Comment: I think you need to show us what is actually in your array (with `Data::Dumper` or another tool). Perl does not support arrays of arrays, only arrays of scalars (where the scalars could be references to arrays or other data structures).

Comment: To follow up on mob I'd like to see what you are currently doing.  I suspect you don't really have an array of array or even an array of scalars (which is what you'd like I think).  It always helps to show code.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know about [Perl references](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)?

Perl doesn't really have a data structure called an *Array of Arrays*. What you have is an array, and each member of that array contains a memory location of another array.

When you *pop* an entry from your array, you're not getting an array, but a *references* to another array.

I'm using [Data::Dumper](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html), to see my data structure:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

use Data::Dumper;

my @array = (
    [ 1, 2, 3 ],
    [ 4, 5, 6 ],
    [ 7, 8, 9 ],
);

say Dumper \@array;
```

Here's my output:

```
$VAR1 = [
        [
            1,
            2,
            3
        ],
        [
            4,
            5,
            6
        ],
        [
            7,
            8,
            9
        ]
        ];
```

This is what an *array of arrays* looks like..

Let's use [pop](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pop.html) to pull off that last row:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

use Data::Dumper;

my @array = (
    [ 1, 2, 3 ],
    [ 4, 5, 6 ],
    [ 7, 8, 9 ],
);

my $row_ref = pop @array;  #row_ref _points to_ an array. 

say Dumper  $row_ref;
```

This prints out:

```
$VAR1 = [
          7,
          8,
          9
       ];
```

So, `pop` is working. It's that it returns a *reference* to an array. If we need an actual array, we to *dereference* the reference:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

use Data::Dumper;

my @array = (
    [ 1, 2, 3 ],
    [ 4, 5, 6 ],
    [ 7, 8, 9 ],
);

my $row_ref = pop @array;      # Returns a reference to an array

my @last_row = @{ $row_ref };  # Dereferencing $row_ref to get @last_row

# Now, we can treat @last_row as our array

for my $index ( 0..$#last_row ) {
    say "\$last_row[$index] = $last_row[$index]";
}
```

This prints out:

```
$last_row[0] = 7
$last_row[1] = 8
$last_row[2] = 9
```

If you're not getting something like this, it could be that your data structure isn't what you think it is. Use `Data::Dumper` to dump it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
my $aoa = [
   [ 'a', 'b' ],
   [ 'c', 'd' ],
   [ 'e', 'f' ],
];

my $last_ele = pop(@$aoa);   # [ 'e', 'f' ]
```

If you got something else, you had something else. You can inspect your data structure using

```
use Data::Dumper;

print(Dumper($aoa));   # A scalar
    -or-
print(Dumper(\@aoa));  # A reference
  -but not-
print(Dumper(@aoa));   # XXX This won't show @aoa.
```

Comment: Interesting you mention only passing a scalar to dumper. I try to only do scalar refs with it because it looks terrible. But are you saying this because the array or reference gets flattened into a list and dumper no longer shows the data structure as a whole?

Comment: @Gabs00, I kinda lied. There's no information lost by using `Dumper(@aoa)` if you know that `Dumper(@aoa)` was used instead of `Dumper(\@aoa)`, but it's less confusing if you always pass a scalar. Specifically, `my @a = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]; print(Dumper(@a));` is more likely to miss the fact that you used `[]` instead of `()` than `print(Dumper(@a));`. It's also easier to explain the error with the output of the latter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing something like this

```
my @aoa = (
  [ 'aa', 'ab', 'ac' ],
  [ 'ba', 'bb', 'bc' ],
  [ 'ca', 'cb', 'cc' ],
);

sub return_last_row {
  pop @_;
}

my @last_array = return_last_row(@aoa);
```

which isn't working because the last element of `@aoa` is the array *reference* `[ 'ca', 'cb', 'cc' ]`, so you're getting the equivalent of

```
my @last_array = ( [ 'ca', 'cb', 'cc' ] )
```

i.e. you now have a one-element array containing an array reference.

The best solution is to accept that you have a reference and work with it, so the call would be

```
my $aref = return_last_row(@aoa);
```

and you can print, say, the second element using

```
print "$aref->[1]\n";
```

or, if you must have a real array then you can write

```
my @arr = @{ return_last_row(@aoa) };
```

and print the same value with

```
print "$arr[1]\n";
```

**Note**, however that in first option, `$aref` is a reference to the same data that used to be the last element of `@aoa`, so if you modify it then you will change that data. On the other hand, it is more efficient - in terms of both memory and speed - than the second option, which copies all the data from the original array to a new one.

---

**Update**

To actually answer your *question* *"Can I somehow make pop() return only an array instead of an array of arrays?"* you could do what I described above within the subroutine, so it would look like this instead

```
sub return_last_row {
  @{ pop @_ };
}
```

but as I described, this is less efficient than just using the original array reference.

In addition, do you *really* want to remove the last element from the original `@aoa`? I would be more inclined to leave it in place and do just

```
sub return_last_row {
  @{ $_[-1] };
}
```